# Send JSON with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Is there anything special I have to do to a JSON object before I send it with AJAX? My code looks like this:

```
runAjax(JSON.stringify(data));
```

}

```
function runAjax(JSONstring)
{
    ajax = getHTTPObject();
    var params = "?data=" + JSONstring;
    ajax.open("POST", "createtrip.php", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = serverSpeaks;
    ajax.send(params);
}
```

Right now the server is not receiving the data. I get null on the server side but the client side JSONString is set. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you can check with Firebug if you have an error or call to server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sending data over POST, you don't need the `'?'` character at the beginning of the `params` variable, also I recommend you to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent) the JSONString to avoid problems.

Note that you are missing the `var` statement for the `ajax` variable, this is declaring it globally (window.ajax) and I think that you don't need it globally...

```
function runAjax(JSONstring) {
  var params = "data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSONstring), 
      ajax = getHTTPObject();

  ajax.open("POST", "createtrip.php", true);
  ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
  ajax.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
  ajax.onreadystatechange = serverSpeaks;
  ajax.send(params);
}
```

Comment: my var statement is at the beginning of the file as I use if for other things.

Comment: I know this is about THREE YEARS after the fact... but in JavaScript scope is with respect to the function.  So CMS's usage of `var` there is completely appropriate.  Just wanted to point that out for anyone who might wonder why it was there.  Scope in JS is a bit different than other languages we may be used to.

Comment: It would be better if you remove these two lines : ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
  ajax.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

Answer (score 0):

You should pass through an encoder to send the data correctly. Of course you would first have to see that the variable "data" is well formed as "JSON".

[lib to encode/decode](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-url-decode-encode.html)

other link
[encode/decode](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/encdec/encode-decode.html)

Answer (score 0):

The server can deal with post body like name1=value&name2=value2.

If you are using PHP, you can receive the json string by:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: But can it deal with "?data=value"?

Comment: Did you try to monitor the HTTP traffic using firebug or wireshark? They can give you more information about this Ajax request.